# Rails Controller include within include

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, model-view-controller, include

I have Ruby on Rails API and I want to render a model with all it's assigned data (over multiple levels). My model structure looks like this:

```
class Race < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :efforts, :dependent => :delete_all
end

class Effort < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :race
    has_many :segment_efforts, :dependent => :delete_all
end

class SegmentEffort < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :effort
```

So, when the user calls /race/1, he should get the race with the ID 1, all efforts, that belong to race 1 and all segmentefforts that belong to the selected efforts. Is that possible in rails? I only found out, that you can render associated objects with :inlude, like this:

```
render json: @race.to_json(:include => [:efforts])
```

But I wonder, if it is somehow possible to include the segmentefforts within the efforts and if that would be a smart practise to do. Or maybe there are better ways to load these resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, you can use [jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) to build more robust JSON structures to respond to queries with.

First you want to make sure your SQL queries are efficient. Rails will handle that for you if you use eager loading:

```
@race = Race.includes(efforts: :segment_efforts).find(params[:id])
```

Then your view would look something like this:

```
# app/views/races/show.json.jbuilder
json.(@race, :name, :foo)
json.efforts(@race.efforts) do |effort|
  json.effort_name effort.name
  json.someother_attr effort.someother_attr
  json.segment_efforts(effort.segment_efforts, :another_attr)
end
```

Be sure to check out the [jbuilder examples](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) to get an idea of what's possible with the syntax.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, that's what I've been looking for! :)

Comment: Would it be possible to say that `SegmentEffort` belong to `Effort` and `Race`? You could then include it with `@race.to_json(:include => [:efforts, :segment_efforts])`?